# Select box enable a dinamic text box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would need to generate dynamic textboxes after an event by the select option ex:

```
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="textControll">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="other">3</option>
          </select>
        <div id="kids">
          Child:
          <input type="text" name="aggr">
          <input type="button" id="add_kid()" onclick="addkid()" value="+" />
        </div>
```

when I choose other from the menu, I would like a textbox to appear that is dynamic in turn, i.e. that I can add others from it with an incremental value

```
        <script>

          function addkid() {

            if (i <= 3) {
              i++;
              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div.innerHTML = 'Child: <input type="text" name="aggr_'+i+'">'
                + ' <input type="button" value="-" onclick="removekid(this)">';
              document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
            }
          }
          
          function removekid(div) {
            document.getElementById('kids').removeChild(div.parentNode);
            i--;
          }
        </script>
```

the addKid function increases and deletes the existing textbox correctly but I would like this to be done only by **selecting other**

P.S or rather chg would appear (enable) after selecting other

Do you know how I could solve?
Thanks!!

Comment: still not clear what u are looking for. when you select 1 then one text box appear if select 2 then 2 text box appear if select other then you can add as many as text box you want is it your requirement?

Comment: No only when selecting other gives me the possibility to create a dynamic text box that is a text box with a + next to it which in turn creates other text boxes only under other

Comment: so u need a text box creation enability with + symbol when you select other right?